# Guice Problem with Tests

Tags: guice

Hey I wrote a LudoGame and now I like to test it with a little GuiceInjection^^
I have an Interface IDie for my die. Now for the game I only need an IDie instead of a realdie => in tests I simply give the LudoGame a MokeDie to set up the Numbers I like to roll.
The IDie has only one method: roll() which returns a int.
BUT the mokeDie now has another public method: sendNextNumber() (should be clear what this does^^)
Now I like to @Inject a Die and if @UseMokeDie is before a Test I'll like to pass the MokeDie
but I'm very new to Guice...
Need some advices please!
Thx for Answers

Answer (score 3):

For tests, your best bet is to *manually* construct instances. For example:

```
public void testAdvance() {
  MockDie die = new MockDie();
  LudoGame game = new LudoGame(die);
  die.sendNextNumber(5);
  game.advance();
}
```

Comment: mhm it's working now... I added the sendNextNumber() to the Interface with @ForTestingOnly and then created 2 Modules. 1 For the tests and 1 for the real game (or the SmokeTest)

Comment: You should really still not be using Guice in plain unit tests - in some integration tests it is viable though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(IDie.class).toInstance(new MockDie());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(injector.getInstance(IDie.class).getClass().toString());
```